# add rows to datatable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

We are using Google Table Charts, In the `$("#loginsubmit")` function i am looping through a `webservice` to get `id` , `firstName` and `lastName` . Now i want to add all the values in the `DataTable` [one row for each `id`] which is in the `drawTable` function. How do i go about it?? Any help is appretiated.

```
 $("#loginsubmit").live("click", function () {
     for (var i = 58; i < 63; i++) {
         var request = new Request();
         request.service = "http://88.80.223.163:8080/lumiin-service/lumiin/control/communication/" + i;
         RequestHandler(request, drawTable);
     }
 });

 function drawTable(data) {
     //alert(JSON.stringify(data.contents.id) + 'Eshan');
     var datat = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     //alert(a);
     datat.addColumn('string', 'Id');
     datat.addColumn('string', 'First Name');
     datat.addColumn('string', 'Last Name');
     datat.addColumn('string', 'Place');
     //alert(data.contents.id + 'Eshan1');
     datat.addRows([
         [JSON.stringify(data.contents.id), JSON.stringify(data.contents.prospectId.firstName), JSON.stringify(data.contents.prospectId.lastName), JSON.stringify(data.contents.place)], ]);
     var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
     table.draw(datat, {
         showRowNumber: true
     });
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you're creating the entire table with each row of data, including adding all the columns for each row.

Comment: @roviuser yes you are right...but i have no idea how to go about this?? can you help me?? just a direction.